# AS3 Duplicate function

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, function, duplicates

So i was playing little with this code and attempting do duplicate it so that dynamic text for flashtip2 will show different values from xml like: return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 + 0 + 0)) + 13); - on the dynamic text flashtip2. How can i duplicate this without errors of duplicated values? My code is:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var xmlData:XML = new XML();

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadXML);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.cbbh.ba/kursna_bs.xml"));

/* This loads the XML */
function LoadXML(e:Event):void {
xmlData = new XML(e.target.data);
parseData(xmlData);
 }

 /* This gets the data for today's tip */
 function parseData(mTip:XML):void {

     var itemXMLList:XMLList = XMLList(mTip..item);
     var count:int = itemXMLList.length();
     var finalcount:int = count - 1;
     //trace(finalcount);

 function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
 {
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 + 0 + 0)) + 12);  //+ 12 or 13 
 }
 var randomNum = randomRange(0, finalcount);
 trace(randomRange(11, 11));

 flashTip.htmlText = mTip.channel.item[randomNum].description.text();

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Getting node by currency**

To get exact node with needed currency, you could search by currency code. If currency can't be found in the list, function will return null;

```
function getNodeByCurrency(currency:String, currencyData:XML):XML {
    var items:XMLList = currencyData..item;
    var i:uint, len:uint = items.length();

    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        if (String(items[i].title).indexOf(currency) != -1) {
            return items[i];
        }
    }

    //Currency isn't found
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
trace(getNodeByCurrency("USD", xmlData));
trace(getNodeByCurrency("CAD", xmlData).description);
```

**Getting random value from the predefined range.**

If you want random value from the range, you should change your function a bit:

```
function randomValueFromRange(minValue:int, maxValue:int):int {
    return minValue + Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue);
}
```

> without errors of duplicated values?

If you want exclude some value from the range (generate unique value), you can pass previous value:

```
function randomValueWithExclude(minValue:int, maxValue:int, excludeValue:int):int {
    var result:int = randomValueFromRange(minValue, maxValue);
    while (result == excludeValue) {
        result = randomValueFromRange(minValue, maxValue);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is example how to use it. Every 8 seconds show new tip, that isn't equal to previous:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(8000);
var count:int = itemXMLList.length();
var currentValue:int = -1;
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
timer.start();

function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
    currentValue = randomValueWithExclude(0, count, currentValue);
    flashTip.htmlText = mTip.channel.item[currentValue].description.text();
}
```

Comment: i am not trying to get random number but specific one. I am fetching data from: http://www.cbbh.ba/kursna_bs.xml and it looks like this in dynamic text field Jedinica: 1
   Kupovni za devize: 0.64000897 
   Srednji za devize: 0.641613 
   Prodajni za devize: 0.64321703

Comment: so i need another text box showing me the same info but with different numbers so this is a exchange list for Turkish money I need another text box for USA for example and so on...

Comment: so how to arrange this i like this text format all i need is to copy dynamic text to flashtip2,3,4,5  with data for USA, TUR, CHN...

Comment: I will use dynamic text boxes to place them where i want in stage but with specific data so USA will be next to TUR and so on...

Comment: I see. So you want to know, at what position in XML is exactly information about USD or CAD? So you will be able extract it and place whatever you want.

Comment: yes thats it so i need format like: Jedinica: 1 Kupovni za devize: 0.64000897 Srednji za devize: 0.641613 Prodajni za devize: 0.64321703 and i will later add graphic for data like state flag and colors and place another info with different country flag to that like TUR next to CAD and so on

Comment: Infos are placed inside text box (dynamic text)

Comment: I have updated answer with utility function to search for node by currency.

Comment: so can you write me down complete code i am still getting some errors